Upgrade angular app from version 8 to v16
I have an Angular project on version 8. I have to update it to Angular 16 using Node 18. I have no idea on what is needed to pay attention during the procedure. I have installed Node 18 and tried to update Angular by incrementing it one by one.
I tried to follow these steps and update to Angular 9 but I get errors these for incompatible peer dependencies:

Package "@agm/core" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.13").
Package "@agm/core" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.13").


Go one version at a time. This error is happening because @agm/core has "@angular/core" version 5 || 6 marked as a dependency. You can use --force to bypass this check I believe, but you really should look into these dependencies to see if they still work. https://github.com/sebholstein/angular-google-maps/blob/1.0.0-beta.5/package.json This lib hasn't updated in 4 years, so maybe look for a replacement that supports higher versions of Angular. You'll need to resolve dependencies like this all along the way.

Please at least search for a common phrase in the error message on the site, like incompatible peer dependency to do some research.

What is your node version?
If you are upgrading using node 18 then I think due to this. you are getting this error.
Downgrade your node version and you need to upgrade it with your angular.
For node and Angular compatibility , please refer below link.
https://angular.io/guide/versions
